# git st Failed to run command 'st': Result too large

Tags: git

I haven't set up my git aliases yet but accidentally ran `git st` before doing so. I get this:

```
$ git st
Failed to run command 'st': Result too large
```

What's going on?

For the record, `git status` runs fine. I don't want to set up the git alias `st` for status until I've worked out what this problem is.

Comment: Have you checked your aliases? `git st` is not a git command in my pc (git version 2.5.0)

Comment: That's exactly the point. This is *before* I've set up my aliases.

Comment: have you tried to init a new empty repository and try there the command? maybe you've set the alias in a local repository and it's not global.

Comment: You can check the aliases in use with `git config --get-regexp "alias.*"`.

Answer (score 0):

Debug this by setting the `GIT_TRACE` environment variable. This is what I get:

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git st
12:21:45.322173 git.c:560               trace: exec: 'git-st'
12:21:45.322898 run-command.c:335       trace: run_command: 'git-st'
git: 'st' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

So, we know that it's trying to execute `git-st`; my guess is that you have a `git-st` executable in $PATH?